# pandas string replace multiple character in a cell

Tags: python, pandas, str-replace

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['123']})
     a
0  123
```

I want to replace 1 with 4, 2 with 5, and 3 with 6

So this is the desired output

```
     a
0  456
```

How can I achieve this using `pd.str.replace()` ?

Comment: You'd have to do `df['a'].str.replace('1', '4').str.replace('2', '5').str.replace('3', '6')` to use `pd.str.replace()`, but Quang's answer is better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `.replace` (not `.str.replace`) with option `regex=True`:

```
df['a'] = df['a'].replace({'1':'4', '2':'5', '3':'6'}, regex=True)
```

Output:

```
     a
0  456
```